# Smarty array with dot in key

Tags: php, smarty

I have an array in PHP that looks like this:

```
$config['detailpage.var1']
$config['detailpage.var2']
$config['otherpage.var2']
$config['otherpage.var2']
...
```

To access it in Smarty I would do

```
$smarty->assign('config', $config);
```

With this template:

```
{$config.detailpage.var1}
```

Unfortunately this does not work, due to the dot in my array key "detailpage.var1", which for Smarty is the delimitor for the array elements.
As I don't want to rewrite my config array (cause it is used in many other places), my question is:

Is there any other notation I could use that works with the dots in the array keys?
Or can I somehow escape them?

Comment: I would also advise you to follow the coding standards of Zend: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

Comment: I definitely agree. But the project already has this variables. But would be a good thing to think of in the future! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've "accidentally" found the answer to this question after I was looking myself for an answer here. In this case I'm using hostnames as keys which always have dots. You can access them with {} around the dotted key name. 
e.g. `{$var.foo.bar.{"my.hostname.example.com"}.ipaddress}` .

This "escaped" syntax can also be used in cases where you have to expand a variable that contains a dot. e.g. `{$var.foo.bar.{$var.bingo}}`

Answer (score 7):

Not the smartest solution but it should work:

```
{assign var=myKey value="detailpage.var1"}
{$config.$myKey}
```

Comment: Good idea. +1
But I would prefer the workaround solution from RobertPitt, as it is automated for all variables in the $config-Array.

Using yours I would have to put the assign line in front of every (first) config-variable call.

Answer (score 3):

You can reformat the keys in the associative array to comply with Smart Compiler Regex'es.

```
$configS = array();
foreach($config as $key => $value)
{
    $key = str_replace('.','_',$key);
    $configS[$key] = $value;
}
$smarty->assign('config', $configS);
```

OR

```
$configS = array();
foreach($config as $key => $value) $configS[str_replace('.','_',$key)] = $value;
$smarty->assign('config', $configS);
```

Now you can use `{$config.detailpage_var1}` instead, just substitute the `.` with a `_`.

---

Walk the array,

```
function cleanKeysForSmarty(&item,$key)
{
    return array(str_replace('.','_',$key) => $value);
}
$smarty->assign("config",array_walk_recursive($config,'cleanKeysForSmarty'));
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: Would be a good workaround to use. +1 Thanks. But I'll wait if someone will come up with a better solution before accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using array notation {$config['detailpage.var1']} or {$config[detailpage.var1]}.

Comment: Does not work. The [ is not allowed:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Syntax Error in template "index.htm" on line 32 "{$config.[detailpage.var1]}" - Unexpected "[", expected one of: "{" , "$" , "identifier" , INTEGER'

I tried {$config{detailpage.var1}} as well

Answer (score 0):

Use:

{$array["key.with.dot"]}

Or:

{$array["key.with.dot"]["subkey"]}